# Spring Data / Hibernate Table DDL creation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

with the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` it's possible to auto generated table from entities.

What I need is that only some specific entities should be generated to tables in database an the rest of the entities do nothing.

It this possible ?

Comment: what do you mean by "the rest of entities do nothing" ? Seems there are not entities at all...

Comment: I want that the rest of the entities are not auto created in the database.

Comment: why do you need this ? How do you handle the ddl part for these entities ?

Comment: It's one database, one schema.
Some tables are mine, other tables are from another software. And the entities from the software should not be auto-created.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420562/how-do-i-skip-certain-entity-classes-from-being-created-as-a-table-in-h2-in-me

Comment: @viglu does entities from another software are in read-only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pcsutar already commented, impl said SchemaFilterProvider

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is your question here? https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/i-would-really-like-to-know-more-about-the-update/5455

Like I wrote there already, you shouldn't use hbm2ddl for anything other than development purposes. Use a proper schema management tool like Liquibase or Flyway.